# **Close** Two loops in Ruby program

Tags: ruby, genetic-algorithm

I have a `findMax` function that calculates the max of distance in an array. For example,

- input: `[10, 15, -5, 0, 20]`
- output: `25 = 20 - (-5)`

This is the code:

```
def findMax array
  max = 0
  index1 = 0
  index2 = 0
  while index1 < array.length
    while index2 < array.length
      if array[index1] - array[index2] > max
        max = array[index1] - array[index2]
      end
      index2 += 1
    end
    index1 += 1
  end
  return max
end
```

As far as I know, the algorithm is correct; if it write in javascript, it works. I don't know why `index1` does not change.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: What does the output `25 = 20 - 5` mean? Is it a string? I know it is not expressing a numeric calculation since it would then not make  sense.

Comment: @sawa: It seems like it should be `25 = 20 − −5`, so just a typo.

Comment: Ruby doesn't have functions. It has methods. One of Ruby's conventions is to use "snake-case" for names of variables and methods (`find_max`, not `findMax`). That is, each character should be a lowercase letter, digit or underscore, with the latter used mainly as a stand-in for a space. You don't have to adopt the convention, but 99%+ of us do.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look correct. The second index will stay pointing to the last element after the first iteration.

So place the

```
index2 = 0
```

After

```
while index1 < array.length
```

Alternatively, here is a way simpler implementation to take advantage of Ruby's awesomeness:

```
array.minmax.map(&:abs).reduce(:-).abs
```

Comment: Thanks for support and I think `abs` function is no need

Comment: I think `array.minmax.reverse.reduce(:-)` will do what OP needs as a one-liner, although I'd probably do `a_min, a_max = array.minmax; a_max− a_min` for readability (or even `array.max − array.min` if I didn't care about the performance hit), the method chaining is cool, but requires thinking about when reading back.

Comment: docongthanh, close, but no cigar. `.map(&:abs)` is not unnecessary, it's incorrect. You need to keep `.abs` or (better, I think) `-array.minmax.reduce(:-)` or (best, says I) @Neil's #2. (Asleep at the switch, ✅?)